# auto.arima vs corARMA: AR coefficient greater than 1

Tags: r, time-series, lme4-nlme, arima, generalized-least-squares

Using R and the [`nlme` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nlme/versions/3.1-137/topics/nlme), I tried to fit a `gls` model with a `corARMA` correlation structure, but ran into memory issues. As described in [this post](http://environmentalforest.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/compensating-for-autocorrelation-in.html), I thought I would first fit an `lm` model, estimate the correlation structure of the residuals using `auto.arima`, and use the coefficients estimated by `auto.arima` in the `corARMA` function, in the hope that this would require less memory.

Here are the `auto.arima` results:

```
Series: res3 
ARIMA(4,0,1) with zero mean 

Coefficients:
        ar1      ar2     ar3      ar4      ma1
      1.3134  -0.3002  0.0089  -0.0442  -0.7908
s.e.  0.0274   0.0187  0.0131   0.0114   0.0260

sigma^2 estimated as 0.01523:  log likelihood=10807.6
AIC=-21603.2   AICc=-21603.19   BIC=-21557.09
```

So, in the `gls` call, I used:

```
correlation = corARMA(value = c(1.3134, -0.3002, 0.0089, -0.0442, -0.7908)
                      ,form = ~date, p = 4, q = 1, fixed = TRUE)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in corARMA(value = c(1.3134, -0.3002, 0.0089, -0.0442, -0.7908),  : 
parameters in ARMA structure must be < 1 in absolute value
```

So why is it that parameters in the corARMA call must be $< 1$ in absolute value whereas `auto.arima` can return parameters $> 1$?
What would be the best way to estimate the correlation structure before fitting the `gls` model?

Comment: The [ARMA process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive%E2%80%93moving-average_model) needs to be [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process). It can't be stationary with an AR term greater than one. My advice: plot, plot, plot.

Comment: Post your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same strategy and I had exactly the same issue. It seems that parameters > 1 are possible for explosive time series. 
For the parameter that should be > 1 from your `auto.arima` results, try to set it to 0.99 in your GLS model without using the argument `fixed = TRUE`. The model will use the value that you provide as starting value and should finally adjust it to a value similar to your results from `auto.arima`.

It worked for me so I hope it will also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

your auto.arima model is probably WAY over-modelled as the sum of the ar coefficients is approximately 1. suggesting non-invertibility perhaps due to the near cancellation as a result of the ma(1) coefficent . GLS appears to be slightly smarter as it CORRECTLY flagged the model . Post your data and I will give you more definitive corrections.

Your data could easily be random or driven by deterministic components like level shifts , seasonal pulses , local time trends AND of course possible anomalies.

ARIMA model building follows the following paradigm (ITERATIVE MODEL IDENTIFICATION)  https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf

Comment: If you are happy with my response please accept it to close the question